# Which version of Flash Player for Mac, is packed without hardware acceleration?

Tags: plugins, flash-player, hardware-acceleration

I am currently experiencing issues with flash player plugin in all my web browsers (safari, chrome, firefox)

and, NO, disabling it with the enable acceleration option, doesn't work, it's kind of grayed out and checked at the same time

recently, I had a flash player what ran smoothly but one of my automatic updates, messed the web flash plugin

does anyone know the last flash player version that was packed without built-in hardware acceleration, or with it disabled by default?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware acceleration was introduced with Flash 10.1, so any version prior to that should alleviate any problems you're having. That said, many sites will REQUIRE you to have the latest version, so it will probably end up being more detrimental to your browsing experience.

Comment: thanks, I am aware of that, I am planning to install flash player w/o hardware acceleration on firefox, the browser that I use the most, in order to try some essentials web pages (essentials to me anyway)
and then instal flash player with acceleration only for chrome, to use with youtube and alike